# Invite Friends using Facebook Lite app Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have implemented the Facebook invite friend in my app. It is working fine when I have installed the Facebook Application in my device. But if I uninstall the Facebook app and Download the Facebook lite application then it is not working.
Here is my code snippet.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
public void openDialogInvite(final Activity activity) {
    String AppURl = "**************";  //Generated from //fb developers
    CallbackManager sCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
        AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                .setApplinkUrl(AppURl)
                .build();

        AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(activity);
        appInviteDialog.registerCallback(sCallbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {
                        Log.d("Invitation", "Invitation Sent Successfully");
                        System.out.println("test onSuccess");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        System.out.println("test  on cancel");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                        Log.d("Invitation", "Error Occured");
                        System.out.println("test Error" + e.getMessage());

                    }
                });

        appInviteDialog.show(content);
    }

}
```